# Is it okay to store access tokens on clients computer when using AuthenticationContext from ADAL

Tags: c#, wpf, azure

I am building a WPF application and I am using AuthenticationContext from ADAL at each startup right now and would like to cache the access tokens in some way not having to prompt the user each time my application start.

I am given refresh tokens and access tokens. I am not sure if its accepable to just serialize them on disk with the application. Is there anything I should be aware of?

Working with ADAL, is there anything build in for helping me serialize/deserialize the context and get it at startup. (Only found deserialize on AuthenticationResult sofar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own custom cache.  Vittorio talks about this [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/01/getting-acquainted-with-adals-token-cache/).  Scroll down to the "Dude, Get Your Own" section.

And the sample code he references that uses credential manager is available [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AAL-Native-Application-to-fd648dcf/sourcecode?fileId=96196&pathId=1866494180).

You could probably just use this as-is based on what you've described.

Comment: Ye, just what i needed.